# loss function for neural network with matrix output

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, matrix

I want to train a neural network with $\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ symmetric and positive definit matrix output. Are there rules which loss function ( in dependence of the predicted matrix $A_{\text{pred}}$ and $A_{\text{true}}$ ) to choose? I guess MSE on the flattened matrices equales Frobenius norm of the difference $\|A_{\text{pred}}-A_{\text{true}}\|^2_{\text{Frob}}$. Also, I think something like
$$1-\frac{\|A_{\text{true}}^{-1}A_{\text{pred}}\|^2_{\text{Frob}}}{d}$$
might also be an idea.
Or
$$\frac{\|A_{\text{pred}}-A_{\text{true}}\|^2_{\text{Frob}}}{\|A\|_{\text{true}}}$$ to have better scaling than just the difference.

Comment: Shape of the data (matrix) is not really important (unless it is important for some reason?), it is more important what is your data  (binary vs real-valued, but also other characteristics).

Comment: @Tim So you suggest using MSE of the (flattened) output? Data is real-valued (more precicely, data are real valued matrices). I thought since psd matrices live in a mannifold it would be better to base the loss on a distance in the mannifold instead of euklidian distance.

Comment: *What* is your data?

Comment: Output are real positive definite and symmetric matrices, same as input

Comment: [A post of mine on Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/109504/73930) seems relevant.

Comment: @Philipp123 but what it is? Images of cats? Temperature readings on Mars? Economical data? Uber trip coordinates?

Comment: @Tim Covariance matrices generated either by Gaussian simulated data or simulated structural equation model, sorry if Cross Validated is more focused on real data applications

Comment: If you want your network to output only PSD matrices it's probably a good idea to use some [non-redundant parametrization](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/225152/parametrization-of-positive-semidefinite-matrices)  and not the matrices themselves

Comment: @ J. Delaney Thanks for the links in the link, I use some bilinear layers $W^THW$ to map psd to psd with ReLU on the eigenvalues afterwards. I think I can avoid the redundancy in this way, I'm just not sure how to choose the loss

Comment: @Philipp123 it’s fine, but worth mentioning in the question. They have certain characteristics like symmetry and being non-negative that may be important. Also if this is your data, flattening it would not loose any information.